# #1064, xammp, phpMyAdmin, MYSQL - Why have I an error in mySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') VIRTUAL,
  `title_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))' at line 2
```

Here is a part of script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sggis`.`maps_type` (
  `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `title_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'yandex',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

SQL says that problem is in the 2nd line, but i can't find it.
Code generated by MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [VIRTUAL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) columns you need to specify the expression

> Any legal, deterministic expression which can be calculated is
>   permitted, with the following exceptions:

Your expression is blank.

Comment: I'm newbie in MySQL, and solved problems with workbrench, without code. So could you show some example? expressiom... Smth like.. huh... "id+1" maybe? :)

Comment: well just using 1 should be sufficient for a minimal example

Comment: So then i got "#1904 - Key/Index cannot be defined on a non-stored computed column"

Comment: if you take 2 minutes to read that link in my answer, you wouldn't be asking that.

Comment: don't see any links-_- Maybe i have misunderstanding, 'cause English not my language.

Comment: English isn't my language either but i generally know that blue colored texts are links.

Comment: oh, sorry. Virtual-_- Tnx for an example!Have  found a problem with pk